# iOS 13 navigationBar.barStyle

Tags: swift, statusbar, navigationbar, ios13

I'm applying the new appearance API for `NavigationBar` and I'm struggling with the status bar content (text). On Info.plist I forced to use the light mode because most of the app is white, but in one of my viewControllers, the navigation bar is dark blue (almost black) so the content within this bar needs to be white.

I used to use `navigationBar.barStyle = .black` on versions up to **iOS 12.4**, but for **iOS 13** and above it doesn't work anymore. Follow the code I've tried and failed.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let navController = self.navigationController {
        let navBarAppearance = navController.navigationBar.standardAppearance.copy()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = LayoutBootstrap.colors.primary.solid // Dark blue

        navController.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navController.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    }
}
```

> [Status bar content is black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIBQ2.png)

*PS: On `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I already called a default configuration appearance for `NavigationBar` and Items*

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the status bar style as well

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Comment: It was deprecated in iOS 9 and replaced by preferredStatusBarStyle, but it only works for viewControllers without UINavigationController.